# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Adapter_Exception' with message 'Service container is not set.'

Tags: prestashop

I was just upgrading my prestashop store to 1.6.1.5, everything goes fine but when I was installing a module I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Adapter_Exception' with message
>   'Service container is not set.' in
>   /customers/8/c/0/tinplate-models.be/httpd.www/Adapter/Adapter_ServiceLocator.php:49
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /customers/8/c/0/tinplate-models.be/httpd.www/classes/ObjectModel.php(232):
>   Adapter_ServiceLocator::get('Adapter_EntityM...') #1
>   /customers/8/c/0/tinplate-models.be/httpd.www/classes/shop/Shop.php(131):
>   ObjectModelCore->__construct('1', NULL, NULL) #2
>   /customers/8/c/0/tinplate-models.be/httpd.www/classes/shop/Shop.php(400):
>   ShopCore->__construct('1') #3
>   /customers/8/c/0/tinplate-models.be/httpd.www/config/config.inc.php(95):
>   ShopCore::initialize() #4
>   /customers/8/c/0/tinplate-models.be/httpd.www/index.php(27):
>   require('/customers/8/c/...') #5 {main} thrown in
>   /customers/8/c/0/tinplate-models.be/httpd.www/Adapter/Adapter_ServiceLocator.php
>   on line 49

Hope someone has a solution?

Comment: Does the file `/Adapter/Adapter_EntityMapper.php` exist in your project? It seems to be missing and causing an exception.

Comment: it's there. I have the same error message http://imgur.com/a/nZAie

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
Now I found the reason - the method of *Adapter_ServiceLocator.php* **get()** using private field **$service_container**, which should be intalized with method **setServiceContainerInstance()**. I found the initializing in */config/bootstrap.php*. But it wasnt any includes of the file *bootstrap.php*!

### So you should download fresh version of Prestashop and rewrite the /config/config.inc.php.

Because it must contain

```
 require_once $currentDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap.php';
```

I hope it will help